# This edit was intended to address the author of the post and makes no sense as an edit. It should have been written as a comment or an answer?

Tags: support, rejected-edits

Can someone explain to me why [my edit](https://stackoverflow.com/review/suggested-edits/9512571) was rejected as "trying to address the author"?

I fixed some syntax issues in the code. I understand that there are elements which have to be configured, but I think those syntax errors can be fixed. Or I have to write comment to the author to fix those himself?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Your edit-comment was probably confusing the reviwers (that's the only fault I see with your edit).

Should have been more like

> Adding missing opening braces `[`, corrected typo in identifier, missing comment-marker and some formatting

or if you feel lucky and want to risk it

> Corrected typos in code.

instead of

> Edit [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] element

A better edit-comment goes a long way. That's especially important in code-edits, because those are often *harder* to review properly.

Comment: Ok, but I also change *standartDefaults* to *standardUserDefaults*. Also add commented line to a text which was inside sample code?

Comment: @new2ios: Sorry, didn't list it all. Done that now.

Comment: Thanks, I edit my *edit*. And now it is ok.

Comment: Ah, this time the OP saw it and approved.